# android: imageview inside button

Tags: android, user-interface

I need to be able to show a button in my layout, but I want the button to have an image (small Icon) and text inside of it.

```
something like this:
  ___________________
 / ***   SOME TEXT  /
/_**_______________/
```

where the *s are an image

So what I thought to do is a linear layout with a background and make it clickable - which will probably work, but that means that it won't behave exactly like a button...

Do you have a better idea on how to do that?

Thanks,
e.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your xml layout for the button, add:

```
<Button
  ...
  android:drawableLeft="@drawable/myIcon"
  android:drawablePadding="5dp"
  android:paddingLeft="10dp"
  android:text="My text" />
```

Where myIcon.png is your icon in the drawable folder.

EDIT
Added padding.
EDIT 2:
Added padding to left of the icon.

Comment: This actually works, but what happens now is that the image is completely justified to the left and is on the edges of the button, is there any way to add padding to the image?

Comment: See my edit where I added padding to see if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks, but as the documentation says, the padding is only the space between the drawable and the text and not the space around the drawable. ([button#drawablePadding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawablePadding))

Comment: Sorry, my bad. See my latest edit. You could of course just add the padding to the button itself. Addind padding to top and bottom obviously would also move the icon from the top and bottom edges.

Comment: Can we use this in the ImageButton?

Comment: These don't auto size. So you're screwed on weird devices.

Answer (score 2):

In your XML, you can use ImageButton (which was added in API level 1, so it should be available)

```
<ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/imageBtn"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@drawable/btnSrc"
     />
```

This method doesn't require you to add padding to a side.